# Javascript Value change on select list down

Tags: javascript, php

I have designed and developed a JavaScript code on change on list box..

Below is image :
[image]

Here, on click of Shipping Drop List the Total Amount should be changed... 
Its working for first row, but for second row the JS is not working..

**Table Code:**

```
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Multiple Products</td>
    <td>60</td>
    <td>
        <select name="shippingCompany" id="shippingCompany" class="form-control input-sm mb10" required onchange="getprice();">
            <option selected='selected' value=''>- - - - - - - - -</option>
            <option value='1~190'>DHL (190)</option>
            <option value='4~143'>Aromax (143)</option>
            <option value='5~224'>BlueDart   (224)</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>300                     </td>
    <td>500                         <input type="hidden" name="consolidateFees" id="consolidateFees" value="500">
        <input type="hidden" name="storageFees" id="storageFees" value="300">
        <input type="hidden" name="totalWeight" id="totalWeight" value="60">
        <input type="hidden" name="userCountry" id="userCountry" value="230">
        <input type="hidden" name="orderNo" id="orderNo" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="userId" id="userId" value="7">
        <input type="hidden" name="totalAmtPaid" id="totalAmtPaid" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="shippingCompanySelected" id="shippingCompanySelected" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="shippingAmt" id="shippingAmt" value="">
    </td>
    <td><span id="totalAmt"></span></td>
    <td><button type="submit" name="PayNowBtn" id="PayNowBtn" class="btn btn-info">Pay Now</a></td>
<tr>
```

The Above Table Code is in PHP while Loop

**JS CODE:**

```
function getprice()
    {
        alert("assaas");
        var totalWght = document.getElementById("totalWeight").value;
        var consolidateFees = document.getElementById("consolidateFees").value;
        var storageFees = document.getElementById("storageFees").value;
        var shippingCompany = document.getElementById("shippingCompany").value;     
        var shipSplit = shippingCompany.split("~"); 
        var userCountry = document.getElementById("userCountry").value;

        $.ajax({
            url:"ajax.php",
            type:"post",
            data:{"type":"calculatePrice",totalW:totalWght, cFess:consolidateFees, sFees:storageFees, shipComp:shipSplit[0], uCountry:userCountry },
            success:function(data){
                document.getElementById("totalAmt").innerHTML = data;
                document.getElementById("totalAmtPaid").value = data;
                document.getElementById("shippingCompanySelected").value = shipSplit[0];
                document.getElementById("shippingAmt").value = shipSplit[1];
            }                         
        });  
    }
```

Comment: any error in console ?

Comment: It is likely because you are  not using unique `id` values. Try using the `class` instead.

Comment: can i use class with document.getElementsByClassName("demo"); ???

Comment: I use jQuery, so I am not sure what the base javascript equivalent is, but you have to either grab same-named classes, or isolate the row when the user changes a select, then traverse forwards to grab the next cells values. Something like that. You can not grab the id though because id values are unique, that is why only the first one works.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("totalAmt").innerHTML = data;
```

means that you replace the value of the element "`totalAmt`" always.
So use a separate Id for each element.

Comment: yes but you need to select the right index of that element list( use the row index). otherwise you can set the id as "totalAmt"+iterationVariable

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Friends,

I have used dynamic ID's while creating PHP While loop.. and code is working perfectly..

I have passed that ID to each input ID and JS ID